# Accessing a variable from outside an anonymous function

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, mongoose

I have a route which performs 2 queries in 2 different databases like so:

```
app.post('/location',function(req,res){

    Db.find({id:anId},function(err,doc){
        myDocs=[]
        for (var i = doc.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
            myDocs.push(doc[i])
            otherDocs=[]
            otherDb.find({id:doc[i].id},function(err,doc2){
                for (var i = doc2.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
                    otherDocs.push(doc2[i])
                }
            })
            myDocs.push(otherDocs)
        }
        res.send(myDocs)
    })

})
```

The issue here is that `otherDocs` is local to the anonymous function in `otherDb`, I am not able to access it from outside and push it into `myDocs`. How would I be able to do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't have a scoping problem, you have an asynchronous problem. Because the inside of your loop has asynchronous code, you'll have to wait for the callbacks to finish first before `push`ing them to `myDocs` and `res.send`ing them.

Easiest solution to this would be to make the function `async` and then `await` each inner `.find` (transformed into a `Promise`):

```
app.post('/location',function(req,res){
  Db.find({id:anId}, async function(err,doc){
    const myDocs = [];
    for (const oneDoc of doc.reverse()) {
      myDocs.push(oneDoc);
      const doc2 = await new Promise(res => {
        otherDb.find({id: oneDoc.id}, (err,doc2) => res(doc2));
      });
      myDocs.push(doc2.reverse());
    }
    res.send(myDocs);
  });
});
```

Note that this will iterate through each `oneDoc`'s `find` one-by-one - if you want to send all requests at once rather than in parallel, use `Promise.all` instead.

Comment: won't this be "too synchronous" ?

Comment: thanks, this works perfectly.